# Spinner is not showing when using in Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a Phonegap/Jquery Mobile App in Android using a WebViewClient and when user clicks on the button I want to show a spinner while I load a JNI/javascript function. However I am unable to do so with the code below.

***NOTE:*** If I remove the call to the JNI/Javascript function then the spinner showed up as expected. Helper is a java class that is registered from DroidGap onCreate() method as appView.addJavascriptInterface(helperObject, "Helper");

Also if copy pasted as .html and browsed through browser will work (offcourse I am not calling the JNI/Javascript function that time as well) meaning it shows the spinner provided I have a sleep() time. However when I am using Android it doesn't show. The index.html is in assets/www folder.

```
<head>
<title>Employee Finder</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script> -->
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#findemp').click(function() {
         var empNumber = $("#employeenumber").val();
         showSpinner();         

             var empdetail = JSON.parse(window.Helper.getEmpDetails(empNumber));
         //Above call takes 3-4 sec and is a JNI call meaning calling a java function.

         hidespinner();
    });
});

function showSpinner()
{
    var opts = {
              lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
              length: 7, // The length of each line
              width: 4, // The line thickness
              radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
              rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
              color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
              speed: 1, // Rounds per second
              trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
              shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
              hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
              className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
              zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
              left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();
            $("#loading").append(spinner.el);
}

function hidespinner(){     
    $('.spinner').hide();

}
</script>


</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Find Employee Data</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="searchDetails">    
       <input name="employeenumber" type="text" id="employeenumber"  placeholder="Employee Number" min="13"/>
       <input type="button" id="findemp" data-theme="b" value="Find Employee"/>
       <div id="loading" ></div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="empDetails">
       <p><b>Name: </b></p><p id="name"></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spin.js is ok, but if you're already using JQuery mobile, you're better off using the built-in spinner.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

in the header, and then:

```
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
$.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

shows the built-in jquery mobile spinner.

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

hides the mobile spinner.

Comment: I tried this as well. My problem is that when I try executing this html through Android it doesn't show up the spinner right away after button click as expected. In fact the spinner is not shown at all. Do android need some special permissions to execute this?? I am using a WebViewClient in Android for this.

Comment: Appreciated your quick response jdb1a1.

Comment: I realized that I have a call JSON.parse(window.Helper.getEmpDetails(empNumber)); which eventhough takes time but seems that is messing up with the showing of spinner. If I remove this function and add a sleep then spinner shows up

Answer (score 0):

So using a timeout function seems to be sort of working. Its not a solution but at least I see the spinner for some time and then the function executed.

```
$('#findemp').click(function() {

        showSpinner('#loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
        getempData();
        hidespinner();}, 1000);      
     });

function getempData()
{
    var empNumber = $("#employeenumber").val();     
    var empdetail = JSON.parse(window.Helper.getEmpDetails(empNumber));
   //transition to a result page here
}
```